# Creating column based on index from other df

Tags: python, pandas, join, indexing, merge

I have team names listed as an index in one dataframe and want to create columns in another df based on matching up column labeled Season and Home. Resulting column will have the total number of allstars on that team for that season.

```
        2012-13 2013-14 2014-15 2015-16 2016-17
Cleveland Cavaliers 1   1   2   1   3
Los Angeles Lakers  2   1   1   1   0
Miami Heat          3   3   2   2   1
Chicago Bulls       2   1   2   2   1
```

df I want to add onto looks like so

```
          Date             Visitor  V_PTS                 Home          H_PTS  \
0 2012-10-30 19:00:00  Washington Wizards     84  Cleveland Cavaliers     94   
1 2012-10-30 19:30:00    Dallas Mavericks     99   Los Angeles Lakers     91   
2 2012-10-30 20:00:00      Boston Celtics    107           Miami Heat    120   
3 2012-10-31 19:00:00    Dallas Mavericks     94            Utah Jazz    113   

   Attendance                    Arena                 Location  Capacity  \
0       20562      Quicken Loans Arena          Cleveland, Ohio     20562   
1       18997           Staples Center  Los Angeles, California     18997   
2       20296  American Airlines Arena           Miami, Florida     19600   
3       17634  Vivint Smart Home Arena     Salt Lake City, Utah     18303   

  Yr Arena Opened   Season  
0            1994  2012-13  
1            1992  2012-13  
2            1999  2012-13  
3            1991  2012-13
```

Not too familiar with inner/outer joins, which seems to be what I have been finding on how to approach this problem

been trying to play around with code like this, but I'm just trying to get it to get a column that says H_Allstars and V_Allstars for the specific season not list all of them.

```
allstar = pd.merge(nba, allstar_df, right_index = True, left_on=['Home'])

                 Date             Visitor  V_PTS                 Home  H_PTS  \
0 2012-10-30 19:00:00  Washington Wizards     84  Cleveland Cavaliers     94   
1 2012-11-02 19:30:00       Chicago Bulls    115  Cleveland Cavaliers     86   
2 2012-11-17 19:30:00    Dallas Mavericks    103  Cleveland Cavaliers     95   
3 2012-11-21 19:00:00  Philadelphia 76ers     83  Cleveland Cavaliers     92   
4 2012-11-27 19:00:00        Phoenix Suns     91  Cleveland Cavaliers     78   

   Attendance                Arena         Location  Capacity Yr Arena Opened  \
0       20562  Quicken Loans Arena  Cleveland, Ohio     20562            1994   
1       20562  Quicken Loans Arena  Cleveland, Ohio     20562            1994   
2       18633  Quicken Loans Arena  Cleveland, Ohio     20562            1994   
3       16743  Quicken Loans Arena  Cleveland, Ohio     20562            1994   
4       13687  Quicken Loans Arena  Cleveland, Ohio     20562            1994   

    Season  2012-13  2013-14  2014-15  2015-16  2016-17  
0  2012-13        1        1        2        1        3  
1  2012-13        1        1        2        1        3  
2  2012-13        1        1        2        1        3  
3  2012-13        1        1        2        1        3  
4  2012-13        1        1        2        1        3
```

Comment: Can you format your 2nd dataframe better? It is very hard to read / align given the formatting. I would advise you print `df.head()` and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50124679/edit) your question with what you find.

Comment: Ok with some quick googling I was able to print it out as such using %qtconsole, which I believe is what you meant with formatting better. Thanks for the advice!